# UIView animation repeatcount for multi view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to apply the wiggle animation more than 10 elements.It's working fine for 6 - 9 elements. If the element goes more than 10 wiggle apply successfully but, if I press home button while animation app not response.

My code is:

```
while(subviews)
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"wiggle" context:nil];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];

    [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];

    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:FLT_MAX];

        //wiggle 1 degree both sides
    touchView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.0174532925);

    touchView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-0.0174532925);

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a reference to your views in your app delegate and cancel all animations on `applicationWillResignActive:`.

Comment: Hi Mundi Thanks for reply but i tried it applicationWillResignActive:Method not gets call before app stuck